# Wireless adapter goes missing frequently in my Dell Inspiron 3537 (Windows 10 Laptop)

Tags: laptop, windows-10, dell-inspiron, wifi-configuration

I have **Dell Inspiron 3537 Laptop**. It's WiFi adapter goes missing frequently. Mostly when my laptop wakes up from sleep mode, restarts or shut down and turn on next time. I am not understanding why is it disappearing. When my WiFi disappears the **Wireless Adapter in Device Manager disappears as well**. Means it is like I don't have any Wireless Adapter. The adapter appears back after several restarts.
I tried unchecking **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power** option in device Dell Wireless 1705  properties (Power Management) when it was available.

What could be the problem? I've been searching for the solution since last 10 days. Nothing worked.

Does anybody else facing the same issue on installing Windows 10?

Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: You say *Nothing worked*. What was *nothing*? What have you tried? Have you updated BIOS? Run diagnostics? The WiFi drivers were updated on the 11th. Have you updated those? Is your question really to know if anyone else is facing these issues? Or do you want to know how to fix it?

Comment: I want the issue to be fixed of course.  My BIOS is already the latest version i.e. A8.

Comment: I have tried-
1) I tried unchecking Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power option in device Dell Wireless 1705 properties (Power Management) when it was available.

2) Tried [this](http://www.howto-connect.com/fix-wifi-missing-or-not-working-in-windows-10/) too.

And much more from the forums.

Comment: Did you update the drivers from Dell support?

Comment: Drivers are up to date.

You said drivers were updated on 11th, but they are for 1704/1708 devices. When I searched by using service tag, it showed me 4 older network drivers. But when I did it by just model number it showed 8 drivers in network section including the one that updated on 11th.

One more thing I just noticed. I went to Device Manager and uninstalled Bluetooth device and its driver too. WiFi is not disappearing anymore. I tried rebooting several times to see if its really working. It did. But I can't use BT now.

Comment: Does this really worked or just a coincidence?

Comment: I was not able to look it up by service tag, obviously, so all I saw was by model lookup. You will have to be the one to answer is this is the fix. If after a few days you no longer have the problem, then I'd say yes. At that point you may want to try installing the Bluetooth driver again to see if it will play nice.

Comment: It did not work. The problem still persists. :(

Comment: Maybe the wifi card is loose.You should contact support if your device has a warranty

Comment: Well, it is possible the WiFi adapter might have gone bad.

Comment: @SuiciDoga My product is out of warranty. I contacted Dell's authorized service center. They said they will charge ₹1300 ($19) as their service charge plus hardware replacement charges if any. :(
They're going to reinstall the windows. I told them that I've already done that. They still going to charge ₹1300.

Comment: @A.B. Try replacing the WiFi card your self